# How to automate baking pizza in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

I'm writing a game about making pizza in Corona SDK. When you buy chefs, the new chef is supposed to make some pizzas on its own like automation.

I tried everything I knew about, I couldn't think of anything that would do what I'd like so I ask you guys to help me.

Here is the code I think is relevant:

```lua
local widget = require("widget")

local pizzeria = display.newImage("background.png")
pizzeria.x=160
pizzeria.y=230
pizzeria:scale(1,1)

local pizzas=0
local chefs = 0
local pizzatext = display.newText( "Pizzas:", 100, 200, display.contentWidth*0.6, display.contentHeight * 0.7, native.systemFont, 16)
pizzatext:setFillColor( 10, 0, 0)

local pizzacount = display.newText(pizzas,165,200,display.contentWidth*0.7,display.contentHeight*0.7,native.systemFont,16) 
pizzacount:setFillColor(10,0,0)

local chefstext = display.newText("chefs:",320,200,display.contentWidth*0.7,display.contentHeight*0.7,native.systemFont,16) 
chefstext:setFillColor(10,0,0)

local chefscount = display.newText(chefs,363,200,display.contentWidth*0.7,display.contentHeight*0.7,native.systemFont,16) 
chefscount:setFillColor(10,0,0)

local function pizzamaker( event )
  if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
    pizzas=pizzas+1
    pizzacount.text=pizzas
  end
end

local function addchef( event )
  if("ended" == event.phase) then
    if(pizzas>=5) then
      chefs=chefs+1
      chefscount.text=chefs
      pizzas=pizzas-5
      pizzacount.text=pizzas
    end
  end
end

local pizzamaker = widget.newButton
{
  left = 100,
  top = 400,
  defaultFile="button.jpeg",
  overFile = "button.jpeg",
  label = "Make Pizza",
  height = 50,
  width= 100,
  onEvent = pizzamaker
}

local addchef = widget.newButton
{
  left = 100,
  top = 100,
  defaultFile="pizzachef.png",
  overFile="pizzachef.png",
  height = 50,
  width = 50,
  onEvent = addchef
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timer.performWithDelay(delay, listener, iterations)` so that every `x` milliseconds the listener gets called for `n` iterations. [Here is the corresponding documentation.](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html)

In this case, we would need to delclare a new function which makes pizzas, above the `addChef` function.

```
local function makeChefPizza()
    pizzas=pizzas+1
end
```

Then, we add `timer.performWithDelay` to your `addChef` function:

```
local function addchef( event )
  if("ended" == event.phase) then
    if(pizzas>=5) then
      chefs=chefs+1
      chefscount.text=chefs
      pizzas=pizzas-5
      pizzacount.text=pizzas

      timer.performWithDelay(5000, makeChefPizza, -1) -- This line here
    end
  end
end
```

This will call the `makeChefPizza` every 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) and iterate forever (-1 means forever), see docs.